# Color picker widget for Bokeh plots

Tags: bokeh, color-picker

I have created a scatter plot in Bokeh using python. I would like create a widget that allows users to change the color of the points in the scatter plot. Is there an easy way to do that ? I found a color picker JQuery based widget ( http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), however I am not sure how this can be integrated with Bokeh.

Comment: This could almost certainly be wrapped as a custom extension, see the docs for extending Bokeh here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html Getting help might be easier on the Bokeh public mailing lists, where an iterative, collaborative discussion is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was originally asked, a [ColorPicker](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#colorpicker) widget was integrated.